# php isset() function not working on form validation

Tags: php

I have the following validation in place that I am confused at the way it works. I am doing the standard `isset()` check on each of my fields and I want to print out an error message for each field that is not set. However for some reason it's not behaving at all for me.

```
<?php 

  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    //show hr on click
    $error_design = "<hr> <p id='error_msg'>Please Fix Below Errors: <p>";


    $user_name = $_POST["name"];
    $user_email = $_POST["email"];
    $user_age = $_POST["age"];

    $validation_errors = " ";
    $error_counter = null;

    if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
      $validation_errors .= "<li class='validation_errors'>Please input your name.</li>";
      $error_counter++;
    }

    if (isset($user_email)) {
      $validation_errors .= "<li class='validation_errors'>Please input your email.</li>";
      $error_counter++;
    }

    if (isset($user_age)) {
      $validation_errors .= "<li class='validation_errors'>Please input your age.</li>";
      $error_counter++;
    } elseif (intval($user_age) < 18) {
      $validation_errors .= "<li class='validation_errors'>You must be over 18 years old.</li>";
      $error_counter++;
    }


    if ($error_counter = null) {

      $validation_errors = "<li class='validation_success'>Message successfully sent!</li>";

    }

  }

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>SandBox</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <header>

  </header>

  <form action="" method="post">

    <div class="input_group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>

    <div class="input_group">
      <label for="email">eMail</label>
      <input type="email" name="email">
    </div>

    <div class="input_group">
      <label for="age">Age</label>
      <input type="text" name="age">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit">

    <?php echo $error_design; ?>

    <div>

      <ul>

        <?php echo $validation_errors; ?>

      </ul>

    </div>

  </form>


  <footer></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32513623/2109067) for example of nifty validation class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are using wrong function here.

[isset()](http://php.net/isset) checks if variable is set and is not `null` but when you send form with empty field you'll get empty string. And `isset()` will return `true` in such case.

You have to use [empty()](http://php.net/empty) and just check string length to make sure that something is there.

Answer (score 0):

in your case you're trying to check if the variable is NOT set but in your code you actually checking if the variable IS set so replace every `isset()` with `if(!isset())`

Comment: That's not true. `isset()` also verifies if variable is not `null`, not only if it's declared.

Comment: i mean in his case he's trying to find out if the variable is not set but he's actually checking if the variable is set

Comment: Oh, you should definitely rewrite your answer to make it easier to understand ;)

Comment: sorry, my first language isn't English :)